# Turn a Spark dataframe Groupby into a sequence of dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with a spark dataframe (in scala), and what I'd like to do is group by a column and turn the different groups as a sequence of dataframes.

So it would look something like

```
df.groupyby("col").toSeq  -> Seq[DataFrame]
```

Even better would be to turn it into something with a key pair

```
df.groupyby("col").toSeq  -> Dict[key, DataFrame]
```

This seems like an obvious thing to do, but I can't seem to figure out how it might work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you could do, Here is a simple example

```
import spark.implicits._
val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  (29,"City 2", 72),
  (28,"City 3", 48),
  (28,"City 2", 19),
  (27,"City 2", 16),
  (28,"City 1", 84),
  (28,"City 4", 72),
  (29,"City 4", 39),
  (27,"City 3", 42),
  (26,"City 3", 68),
  (27,"City 1", 89),
  (27,"City 4", 104),
  (26,"City 2", 19),
  (29,"City 3", 27)
)).toDF("week", "city", "sale")
//create a dataframe with dummy data


//get list of cities 
val city = data.select("city").distinct.collect().flatMap(_.toSeq)

// get all the columns for each city
//this returns Seq[(Any, Dataframe)] as (cityId, Dataframe)
val result = city.map(c => (c -> data.where(($"city" === c))))

//print all the dataframes  
result.foreach(a=>
  println(s"Dataframe with ${a._1}")
  a._2.show()
})
```

Output looks Like this

Dataframe with City 1

```
+----+------+----+
|week|  city|sale|
+----+------+----+
|  28|City 1|  84|
|  27|City 1|  89|
+----+------+----+
```

Dataframe with City 3

```
+----+------+----+
|week|  city|sale|
+----+------+----+
|  28|City 3|  48|
|  27|City 3|  42|
|  26|City 3|  68|
|  29|City 3|  27|
+----+------+----+
```

Dataframe with City 4

```
+----+------+----+
|week|  city|sale|
+----+------+----+
|  28|City 4|  72|
|  29|City 4|  39|
|  27|City 4| 104|
+----+------+----+
```

Dataframe with City 2

```
+----+------+----+
|week|  city|sale|
+----+------+----+
|  29|City 2|  72|
|  28|City 2|  19|
|  27|City 2|  16|
|  26|City 2|  19|
+----+------+----+
```

You can also use `partitionby` to group the data and write to the output as

```
dataframe.write.partitionBy("col").saveAsTable("outputpath")
```

this creates a output file for each grouped of `"col"`

Hope this helps!